# Background image repeating when set to none

Tags: html, css, image, media-queries, repeat

I have set the header image to not repeat. However, I'm trying to make the website responsive. When in a smaller browser the image begins to repeat.
[screen snip of website header background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiDbb.jpg)

[header css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5Na9.png)
[media query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4AHO.png)

Comment: include your code in text instead of an image

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what information you need to give us and how to include it. Also, this is a trivial question and is off topic for Stack Overflow - a simple Google for [CSS background image repeat](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+background+image+repeat) will give you lots of resources to help you solve this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property is **no-repeat** not `none`, e.g.  :

```
.bg-image {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```